# Does bleeding damage stack?

Tags: conditions, stacking, starfinder

As an operative I have Bleeding Shot and make level bleeding damage if I hit.

My question: what happens if I do bleeding damage after I hit the first shot. Does the bleeding damage stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is some ambiguity in the rules about bleeding.

While the description of [Bleeding Shot](https://www.aonsrd.com/OpExploits.aspx?ItemName=Bleeding%20Shot) speaks about *bleed damage*, the description of [Bleeding Condition](https://www.aonsrd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=165) uses the terms *bleed effect* or just *bleeding*.

If we assume that both speak about the same thing, which is very likely, then the answer to your question is [here](https://www.aonsrd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=165):

> You take the listed amount of damage at the beginning of your turn each round until this condition ends. Your bleeding can be stopped with a successful DC 15 Medicine check as a standard action, or through the application of any ability that restores Hit Points. **If you take two or more bleed effects, you take only the damage from the worst effect.**

I.e. bleed damage doesn't stack, only the worst bleed effect on the target applies.